# Import JSON to component "TypeError: props.data.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a complete newbie to react and already facing difficulties loading JSON data to a component...

I'm encountering this error:

> "TypeError: props.data.map is not a function"

I honestly don't see where I have gone wrong as i though i have wired things up correctly...

**App.js:**

```
import './App.css';
import Chart from './components/Chart'
import data from './data/test.json';

class App extends Component {

  render() {

      return ([

        <div className="App">
            <Chart data={data}/>
        </div>

      ])
  }

}

export default App;
```

**components/Chart,js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {XYPlot, VerticalGridLines, HorizontalGridLines, LineSeries} from 'react-vis';

const Chart = (props) => {

  const dataArr = props.data.map((d)=> {
      return {x: d.colA, y: d.colB}
  });

  return (
      <XYPlot
          <LineSeries data={dataArr} />
      </XYPlot>
  );
}

export default Chart;
```

**data/test.json**

```
{
    "results": [
        {
          "colA": 1,
          "colB": 0
        },   
        {
          "colA": 2,
          "colB": 1
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: `data.results.map()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `results` key of your data, not the object itself.

```
const dataArr = props.data.results.map((d)=> {
  return {x: d.colA, y: d.colB}
});
```